# how to remove or replace specific chars are between two xml tags [linux, python, lxml, sed, awk,...]?

Tags: python, xml, bash, awk, sed

I'm using LXML library in python for XML parsing.

in a XML file, i have some bad characters that lead to below error in python:

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: CharRef

Before opening and fetching the content of XML file in python, I must remove bad chars from two tags:

1: `<essid cloaked="true">....</essid>`  or `<essid cloaked="false">....</essid>`.

2: `<client-manuf>....</client-manuf>`

the size of XML file is big. so I want to do it  with sed or awk or similar tools.

```
    <crypt>0</crypt>
        <total>20    50</total>
        <fragments>0</fragments>
        <retries>0</retries>
    </packets>
    <datasize>0</datasize>
    <wireless-client number="1" type="established" first-time="Thu Feb 15 16:45:43 2018" last-time="Thu Feb 15 16:45:43 2018">
        <client-mac>08:EA:40:D0:55:43</client-mac>
        <client-manuf>SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO.&#x  ef;&#x  bc;&#x  8c;LTD</client-manuf>
        <essid cloaked="true">&#x   0;&#x   0;&#x   0;&#x   0;&#x   0;</essid>
        <channel>8</channel>
        <maxseenrate>1.000000</maxseenrate>
        <carrier>IEEE 802.11b+</carrier>
        <encoding>CCK</encoding>
        <packets>
            <LLC>0</LLC>
            <data>0</data>
            <crypt>0</crypt>
```

I want to remove the bad chars from these tags (client-manuf and essid).

From:  `<client-manuf>SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO.&#x  ef;&#x  bc;&#x  8c;LTD</client-manuf>`

To (or this):   `<client-manuf>SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO. LTD</client-manuf>`

To (or this):   `<client-manuf>SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO</client-manuf>`

### -----------------------------------------------

From: `<essid cloaked="true">&#x   0;&#x   0;&#x   0;&#x   0;&#x   0;</essid>`

From: `<essid cloaked="false">&#x   0;&#x WiFi 0;&#x MTN  0;&#x   0;&#x   0;</essid>`

To (or this): `<essid cloaked="true"></essid>`

To (or this): `<essid cloaked="true">N/A SSID</essid>`

To (or this): `<essid cloaked="false">WiFi MTN</essid>`

```
for example, two bad chars:

1: 0;

2: &#x
```

This is my solution. but it doesn't work well for my needs:

`sed -e '/<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>*.*<\/essid>/ s/\(&#x\|0;\)//g' a.txt`

Comment: How do you recognize bad characters ? words that contain non alpha numeric symbols ?

Comment: Also, do you need to remove those bad characters in all your file, or do you want to keep them when they are inside other tags ?

Comment: @Aserre the XML file has more than 12000 tags (essid and client-manuf). and i want to remove the bad chars from these two tags.

Comment: @alireza, please check my solution once, also in case if any tag is missing then you could add it like others are there too, let me know.

Comment: @Aserre I got this error when i have bad chars in a xml file: https://imgur.com/a/eDM28

Comment: @stevesliva because i should remove bad chars from file to be able read and parse the xml's elements in python. the number of CMDs is not important. bad chars are lead to this error : `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: CharRef: invalid hexadecimal value.` in python lxml library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sed command didn't look so bad, it just left a lot of whitespace.

Since sed is normally greedy, you may specify any amount of space with " *".

```
cat bad.xml | sed '/<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>*.*<\/essid>/ s/ *\(&#x\|0;\) *//g'
```

On the other hand, if there is some valid text, you might not want to stick it together, so you could add one space per removed pattern:

```
cat bad.xml | sed '/<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>*.*<\/essid>/ s/ *\(&#x\|0;\) */ /g'
```

In the end you might condense multiple spaces to just one:

```
cat bad.xml | sed '/<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>*.*<\/essid>/{s/ *\(&#x\|0;\) */ /g;s/  */ /g}'
```

Note, that the construct {foo;bar} binds the two commands to a block of commands, only operating on the before grabbed pattern. The second pattern would else affect the whole file.

With another masked pair of parenthesis and a masked plus:

```
cat bad.xml | sed '/<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>*.*<\/essid>/{s/\( *\(&#x\|0;\) *\)\+/ missing essid /g;s/  */ /g}'
```

you can s:substitute a repeated occurence of a pattern with just one thing.

```
      s/\( *\(&#x\|0;\) *\)\+/ missing essid /;
      ^  (   (pattern1)   )+ / replacement   /(g now obsolete
         (pattern .......2)
```

The inner pattern is an alternative &#x or 0;. 
The outer pattern is the inner pattern, optionally guarded by blanks like

```
     "0;"
     "0; "
     " 0; "
     " 0;"
     "    0;  "
     "    &#x"
```

and so on.

You want the inner pattern, let's call it X, be repeated once or more than once, therefore the +. But without parens, + only addresses the last character, not the whole pattern.

You have to learn this regex-language. Find a tutorial. You can't ask for every possible variation you will need in your life.

It pays off very rapidly to have good, basic understanding. You don't need to know everything by hearth, but the basic stuff and should have a good estimation, what is possible and what not. Then a repo, to search for the things, rarely used. And then you might only ask the hard/complicated stuff.

Comment: Tnx dear @user unknown, it's better than my solution. my sed has some extra blank/spaces that was bad. it's good. it's greattttttttttttt

Comment: the speed of this solution is very better than previews solution. -i in sed  is very excellent. because we have C code instead of  Python. Tnx u

Comment: SED benchmark was winner. ```cat a.txt | sed '/<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>*.*<\/essid>/{s/ *\(&#x\|0;\) */ /g;s/  */ /g}'```

Comment: dear @user-unknown, a question: i want to remove the text of ESSID tags are contain ```&#x``` or ```0;``` and insert `Unknown-SSID` value in ESSID tags. plz help me. Tnx in advance

Comment: dear @user-unknown, excuse me for bothering you. i tested other ways but failed. for example: a ESSID tag has bad char(s), Since we have one bad char, I want to remove all string within ESSID tag and insert just the ```Bad-SSID```.  for example: ```<essid.....>&#x WiFi 0;</essid>```, result must be: ```<essid.....>bad-ssid</essid>```.  because in my data-mining project, this type of SSIDs are not correct as Target value.  Tnx a lot ;x

Comment: Dear @user-unknown , sorry a lot. Also I checked ```sed 's#\(<Amount>\)[0-9]*\(</Amount>\)#\1'100'\2#g' test.xml``` from http://www.unixcl.com/2010/01/replace-values-in-xml-using-sed-and-awk.html . Also i read your great link but for this situation wasn't great ;(. my incorrect solution: ```sed 's#\(<essid cloaked="\(true\|false"\)>\).*\(&#x\|0;\)\(<\/essid>\)#\1'BAD-SSID'\2#g'```

Answer (score 1):

The right way with **`etree.XMLParser`** object (`lxml.etree` only):

```
import re
from lxml import etree

tags_to_fix = ['clientssss-manuf', 'client-manuf', 'essid']
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)   # recovery mode !
tree = etree.parse("input.xml", parser)

for el in tree.xpath('//*[name()="clientssss-manuf" or name()="client-manuf" or name()="essid"]'):
    el.text = re.sub(r'\w{1,2};\s*', '', el.text).strip()

tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True)
```

The crucial fragment from the resulting `output.xml`:

```
...
<packets>
<crypt>0</crypt>
        <total>20    50</total>
        <fragments>0</fragments>
        <retries>0</retries>
    </packets>
    <datasize>0</datasize>
    <wireless-client number="1" type="established" first-time="Thu Feb 15 16:45:43 2018" last-time="Thu Feb 15 16:45:43 2018">
        <client-mac>08:EA:40:D0:55:43</client-mac>
        <clientssss-manuf>SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO.  LTD</clientssss-manuf>
        <client-manuf>SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO.  LTD</client-manuf>
        <essid cloaked="true"></essid>
        <channel>8</channel>
        <maxseenrate>1.000000</maxseenrate>
        <carrier>IEEE 802.11b+</carrier>
        <encoding>CCK</encoding>
        <packets>
            <LLC>0</LLC>
            <data>0</data>
            <crypt>0</crypt>
</packets></wireless-client>
...
```

Comment: dear @RomanPerekhrest, your python version is 2 or 3?. i'm using ver2. I got this error: `return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer.`

Comment: Is it possible to do it with sed or awk and similar linux tools !?

Comment: dear, tnx a lot for your help. sorry i bothered you. this line was great: ```tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True)```

Comment: Look http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html here. I'm in the cinema now.